# pipes and foreach loops

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Recently, I've been playing with PowerShell, and I've noticed some weird behavior when using pipes and `foreach` loops that I couldn't understand.

This simple code works:

```
$x = foreach ($i in gci){$i.length}
$x | measure -max
```

Makes sense.

But this code won't:

```
foreach ($i in gci){$i.length} | measure -max
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At line:1 char:33
+ foreach ($i in gci){$i.length} | <<<<  measure -max
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

What is the difference between those two methods, and why does the second one fails?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `foreach` statement doesn't use the pipeline architecture, so its output cannot be passed to a pipeline directly (i.e. item by item). To be able to pass output from a `foreach` loop to a pipeline you must run the loop in a subexpression:

```
$(foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem) { $item.Length }) | ...
```

or collect it in a variable first:

```
$len = foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem) { ... }
$len | ...
```

If you want to process data in a pipeline use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet instead:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { $_.Length } | ...
```

For further explanation of the differences between `foreach` statement and `ForEach-Object` cmdlet see the [Scripting Guy blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object.aspx) and the [chapter on loops](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/03/15/chapter-8-loops.aspx) from Master-PowerShell.

Comment: This is the updated [Scripting Guy link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate the `foreach` before piping the resulting Object like you did in the first test:

```
$(foreach ($i in gci){$i.length}) | measure -max
```

Alternatively, use the `%` shorthand to which will evaluate it before piping it as well:

```
gci | % { $_.Length } | measure -max
```

Comment: To be fair. % is shorthand for the foreach-object cmdlet, which is different from the foreach loop which is being used in the question.  :-)