# Why can't you pipe from any powershell statements (foreach, while, etc)?

Tags: powershell, debugging, pipe, statements

Why can't you pipe from any powershell statements like foreach and while ('an empty pipe element is not allowed')?  Is there some engineering limitation?

```
PS /Users/me> foreach ($i in 1,2,3) { $i } | measure

At line:1 char:30
+ foreach ($i in 1,2,3) { $i } | measure
+                              ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement


PS /Users/me> for ($i = 1;$i -lt 10; $i++) { $i } | measure    

At line:1 char:37
+ for ($i = 1;$i -lt 10; $i++) { $i } | measure                                                                         
+                                     ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement


PS /Users/me> $i = 1
PS /Users/me> while ($i -lt 10 ) { $i;$i++ } | measure                                     

At line:1 char:32
+ while ($i -lt 10 ) { $i;$i++ } | measure                                                 
+                                ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

List of powershell statements:

if .. else

Switch

Do .. while

ForEach

For

While

Break

Continue

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ | ForEach-Object {$_.BaseName}`

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? The statements you've shown don't return an object; so there's nothign to pipe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pipes and foreach loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513203/pipes-and-foreach-loops)

Comment: "Ambiguities in the grammar that we haven't been able to resolve." -- Bruce Payette

Answer (score 1):

The PowerShell language statements don't output to the pipeline, as you have noticed (hence the error - "empty pipe element not allowed"). Here are two possible workarounds:

1. Wrap the statement with the `$()` (subexpression) operator. Example:

   ```
   $(foreach ($i in 1,2,3) { $i }) | Measure-Object
   ```
2. Wrap the statement in `{ }` (i.e., make it a scriptblock), and invoke it with the `&` (call/invocation) operator. Example:

   ```
   & { foreach ($i in 1,2,3) { $i } } | Measure-Object
   ```

The difference between the two is that the scriptblock syntax creates a new scope, so variables within that scope are disposed when the invocation completes. In the above two examples, this means that `$i` is defined after executing the first example, but not after executing the second. This difference might be useful depending on what you're trying to do. (For example, I prefer the second syntax when working at a PowerShell command line to avoid polluting the current scope with temporary variables.)